# Undefined Variable

Tags: php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
if ($_GET['size'] == "small") 
{
    $delivery = 5;
    $_GET['size'] = 5;
    $_GET['topping'] = 1;
    if ($_GET['deliverytype'] == "pickup") 
    {
        $total = $_GET['size'] + $_GET['topping'];
    } 
    elseif ($_GET['deliverytype'] == "delivery") 
    {
        $total = $_GET['size'] + $_GET['topping'] + $delivery;
    }
}
echo "Dear " . $name. " your " . $_GET["size"] . " pizza has been ordered.";
echo "You Total is " . $total;

?>
```

I am getting an error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: total in `C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 57`
Can anyone suggest, why is it so?

Comment: echo "You Total is " . $total;

Comment: Borealid's got it right. You need to define $total regardless of if $_GET['size'] is small or not. Or only echo $total in that if.

Comment: @arasmussen..But I need to calculate price based on the selecttion; like; Small: $5 Medium: $10 Large: $15 Each topping costs $1 per topping. Delivery costs $5 extra

Comment: You also should realize that if you change `$_GET['size']` to '5', the sentence is going to read "Dear John, your 5 pizza has been ordered." ...

And like Borealid says, you have to actually write the code for the other cases.  *Then* it will magically work.

Answer (score 3):

If `$_GET['size']` is not "small", `$total` will be undefined.  Ditto if the size is "small", but the "deliverytype" is neither "delivery" nor "pickup".

Comment: But I need to calculate price based on the selecttion; like; Small: $5 Medium: $10 Large: $15
Each topping costs $1 per topping.

Delivery costs $5 extra.

Comment: @Ankur: Then you're going to have to write *that* code.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, add in line 1:

```
$total = 0;
```

To write good PHP, you have to define variables first, or you will have chances to encounter null values.

Comment: I tried adding that line too but its of no use.:(

Comment: because your code logic is incomplete. Try to complete the logic first.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like doing a little bit of hand holding ;), so here's how you probably want the majority of your price calculating function to look.  I can tell you're probably very new to actual programming, so... I figure it helps to see something that kind of paints the entire picture for you.

```
<?php
//These are some dummy variables, these 4 lines
//are pretend data that are theoretically sent form your form
$_GET['name'] = 'John';
$_GET['size'] = 'small';
$_GET['topping'] = 1;
$_GET['deliverytype'] = 'pickup';

//Typically you want to initialize all of your variables
//you're going to use at the top
$name = $_GET['name'];
$size = $_GET['size'];
$total = 0;

//All of the prices are sequentially added to the total
$total += calculate_size_cost();
$total += calculate_topping_cost();
$total += calculate_delivery_cost();

//And THEN, since the data exists, 100% certain it exists
//, this will output your desired information, with no missing variable stuff.
echo "Dear $name  your {$_GET["size"]} pizza has been ordered.";
echo "You Total is $ $total";

//If the size isn't small or large, this will return 5000
//You have to EXPLICITLY state everything that can happen
//If something unexpected happens, you have to place it after
//an "ELSE"
function calculate_size_cost(){
    if($_GET['size'] == "small")
    return 5;
    else if($_GET['size'] == "large")
    return 10;
    else
    return 5000;
}

function calculate_topping_cost(){
    //This is already a number, so, I'm assuming it's the topping price
    return $_GET['topping'];
}

function calculate_delivery_cost(){
    //Will add delivery cost, otherwise this will be zero if
    //it's not pickup
    $delivery_cost = 0;
    if($_GET['deliverytype'] == "pickup"){
        $delivery_cost += 5;
    }
    return $delivery_cost;
}
```

Comment: @anther Indeed I am new to scripting not to programming. This piece of code will help me a lot. Let me try doing this way. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Ankur Yep, us A-names have to stick together. ;]

Comment: Also... ... I'm intrigued to find out how this is scripting vs programming... but.. that can definitely be left for another day's discussion... lol.

Comment: @Anther Its working fine thanks. I have around five toppings but its adding only for one topping and and its not adding for the pizza size. I wanted a total that included Pizza Size, Toppings and Delivery Type. So what I did, $total = calculate_size_cost() + calculate_topping_cost() + calculate_delivery_cost(); But its adding only delivery type and only one topping..:(

Comment: @Ankur This would actually probably go better as a 1 on 1 chatting and teaching session, as right now I foresee this being a long chain of comments back and forth, but it won't hurt to try, lol.  - - - So, you're saying it's not adding something for the size, right?  This means you should probably investigate how and why the "calculate_size_cost()" function works the way it does, and why it isn't doing what you want it to do.  This involves realizing what information it's working with, and then following what it's doing with that information and seeing what's missing.

Comment: I tried not to ask you..lol..yeah, I am trying my best to do that..:)

Comment: But to be frank, I am seriously interested in PHP and all this stuff but the time limitation does not allow me to get into this stuff properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies, of course, in the fact that $total is not declared. Like any programming language, a variable must be declared before being used. PHP is unique in that setting a variable will both declare and set that variable, meaning you have one less step. So, you have three options.

In line one, do `$total = "";` This will set the variable to an empty string. This is not effective, since the message will print regardless of whether or not there is a total price.

You can also make sure that EVERY code path defines `$total` in some way. This will make sure that it will never be undefined. This is similar to the above answer, but helps prevent against the need to error check since it will always be set to a valid value (though error checking is still recommended).

The last, and most preferable method would be to change the last line from

code

```
echo "Dear " . $name. " your " . $_GET["size"] . " pizza has been ordered.";
              echo "You Total is " . $total;
```

to something like

```
if(isset($total))
{
    echo "Dear " . $name. " your " . $_GET["size"] . " pizza has been ordered.";
              echo "You Total is " . $total;
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error in your order. Please try again.";
}
```

This will check to see that a total value was generated before "completing" the order, which prevents the need for a large bulky change to your code or large amounts of error checking. Granted, using `isset()` for error checking is not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: first method is displaying a blank total and last one is directly going to the error message. Any other alternatives to calculate the total based on user selection?

Comment: @Ankur The error message is because the above code that you posted does not handle a Pizza size of medium or large. You'll have to write that code.

Comment: Let me try writing the whole code.

Comment: still it is going to that error message.